# How to delete an object from core data after pressing an UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Currently I have a UICollectionViewCell and when a button (X on top right corner) is pressed on it it's supposed to be deleted from coreData then the UICollectionView is reloaded:

[image: CollectionCell]

As of now when I press the "X" button nothing happens, although I notice that after I stop the simulator and turn it back on the all the items saved in coreData are gone. What should happen instead is only the specific cell where after the "X" is pressed needs to disappear immediately and be removed from coreData. Here is the code:

```
  // MARK: CoreData

  func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
  }

  func deleteFromCoreData() -> Void {
    let moc = getContext()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Movie")

    let result = try? moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
    let resultData = result as! [Movie]

    for object in resultData {
      moc.delete(object)
    }

    do {
      try moc.save()
      print("saved!")
    } catch let error as NSError  {
      print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    } catch {

    }

  }




  @IBAction func deleteButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    self.deleteFromCoreData()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
  }
```

Comment: You don't appear to be using a predicate in your fetch.  You are literally selecting every "Movie" object and then looping to delete each one.

Comment: I'm still new to core data, how would you use a predicate to only delete the currently selected object?

Comment: Before the fetch, you would assign an NSPredicate; something like fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "movieTitle == %@", "Logan")

Comment: And by "movieTitle", that's something I made up...it should literally be the name of the field in your data model that you want to filter on.